# I want to consume a GraphQL web API in .NET

Tags: graphql

I want to consume data from a GraphQL API.
how can I achieve that? I am new to webapi and any help is appreciated

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/bkniffler/graphql-net-client), for example

Comment: Or preferably [this](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-client). Seems more supported by the [Foundation](https://graphql.org/code/#c-net).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the API you want to consume uses HTTP, you should be able to use cUrl, wget, Charles, Postman or even just the URL bar in a browser to make a request.

To write your first query, you can start with the following:

```
query theNameOfMyQuery {

}
```

Now that you have a named query, you can start populating it with whatever fields your GraphQL server is exposing. For a blog example, you might have something like this:

```
query theNameOfMyQuery {
  posts {
    title
    author
  }
}
```

Now, to turn that into something you can request, all you need to do is URL encode it and add it to your URL. A typical URL looks like this:

```
https://www.someserver.com/?query=...&variables=...
```

So for the above example, you would have the above query

```
https://www.someserver.com/?query=query%20theNameOfMyQuery%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20posts%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20title%0D%0A%20%20%20%20author%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D
```

**Some Resources:**

- [Evolution of API Design](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DeKpgHK-bqw) - this video explains some of the concepts of GraphQL and why it exists.
- [howtographql.com](https://www.howtographql.com/) - This is an amazing set of tutorials for every implementation you could imagine